# Perl: Erase lines in a log file using core perl tools

Tags: perl, file

First already reads the articles listed below to learn who to use write a file using core perl.

-http://perlmaven.com/writing-to-files-with-perl

-http://perlmaven.com/appending-to-files

I have a doubt. In my case i need to writing a log file, but is has to be a light log, i mean 50 lines of text for example.

So every interaction is necessary erase the first line and write in the bottom of the log.

What parameter you use to make this happen?

My idea is get all the data from the log and put in some variable like array and delete the first value, then use `open(FILEHANDLE,">filename");` to writhe again the log.

There is not a perl method to make this job using the only the core tools?

Thanks.

Comment: This is typically handled by "log rotation". Search for it online; there are quite a few approaches to the problem (create new log when you reach a certain file size, or create new log every hour etc.). There's also a Perl module, Log4perl, though I don't think it's included in any standard distro.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite inefficient, because as you've  correctly figured out - the only way to do this is to rewrite the log file, less the first line.

If that's all your're doing, then `tail +2` will do the trick.

But I'd suggest that it's quite inefficient to re-write a log file each time you add a line to it, and what you'd be better off doing, is instead write multiple - and delete 'old' ones.

E.g.:

- `stat` the file to get a size, as you're reading metadata, rather than having to read the file content.
- If the size is larger than a predefined limit (50 lines x 80 characters wide would be 4000 bytes) then open a new file.
- List the rest of the files, and if any are 'too old' delete them. (Keep 'current' and 'previous' and you'll always have 4000-8000 bytes of 'log')

Failing that though, you can rewrite the log file in the way you suggest. Be aware that if you do, there'll be a brief period when the log is empty/zero length. And also, that you'll never be able to run `tail -f` on the log.